# Splash Screen not showing in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I first tried updating the splash screen by creating a separate xml file in values folder but that was not working so i changed the themes.xml itself but its still showing the android logo while launching.

`Here's my theme.xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Splash_Screen" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <style name="Theme.CommmuteSplashScreen" parent="Theme.Splash_Screen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/tictactoe_transformed_removebg_preview</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Splash_Screen</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

`Here's my android manifest file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CommmuteSplashScreen"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `not working` means **nothing** specific.

Comment: Depending on the issue it's hard to answer the question. Are you getting the white screen, then app launch? Or are you trying to use the icon as the splash screen, or are you trying to do a custom splash screen.. I struggled with this and left the splash out of my projects and Google Play Store added it automatically with the app icon. Edit your question and explain what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Theme should be set as follows

```
  <style name="Theme.SplashScreen" 

 parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in your SplashScreen.kt you can add the following

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.postDelayed({
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }, 2000)
```

Then in your Manifest you need add the following:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreen"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.SplashScreen">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">

</activity>
```

This cuts the launch time with the Splash Screen to whatever your delay is set at.

This is how I did mine when I was using splash screens

Answer (score 0):

you can to make new activity this activity you need to run in the first add that in manifest

add this code in the splash activity in manifest

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and comment or delete this code main activity from manifest